# How to start a php backend app on Ubuntu remote host AWS

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have `scp`'ed a php backend app (rest server) to a remote ubuntu host on aws. When I was testing it locally I would just do a simple `php -S localhost:8888` for testing the service locally. But now that I have it on a remote host (aws) which has a public ip address, I'm not sure how to start the app. How do I start this app?

So when I try to access the app from any where such as:

`http://<server_addr>/api/get/record/1`

I'll get expected response payload and 200 response code

Answer (score 1):

To make it work try

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8888
```

That way the server is going to listen on any interface. It doesn't work externally because it is listening only on the 127.0.0.1 interface.

With `php -S localhost:8888` if you make a request with `wget` or `curl`, connected via ssh to the php server, it should get the content.

As the other answer says, try apache. The php built-in server is just for local development as the docs estipulate.

> This web server was designed to aid application development. It may
>   also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations
>   that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a
>   full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Edit: Oh, and here you have the AWS docs on how to setup the apache server:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Comment: thanks I'll check this out. I'm a bit of a noob had no idea the build in web server was just for development

Comment: Looks like I have all these steps down from the aws link. I have my environment all configured properly and was able to get to the test pho page. I'm just not sure how to make it applicable to my app. I have an index.php which is the entry point to the rest service. I guess it might be too late and my brain has stopped work :)

Answer (score 0):

To host a PHP based application you will need a webserver with php module enabled. For example you can use apache httpd server (I would suggest you to use if your website is php based). Once your server is installed you should be able to access it on http://yourserveraddress:serverport

To install http with php module on an ubuntu machine you just need to run this command (in most of the cases).

**sudo apt-get install apache2**

Comment: hi @Shantanu this is a backend rest application (I edited my original question and specified its rest) would this work still? You mentioned "use apache httpd server" how can I do this? I have indeed done the following

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

where I appened this this file `ServerName <PUBLIC_IP>`. There does not seem to be good documentation for what I'm trying to do which is to deploy a php application and start it

Comment: @barthelonafan - If it's a php based application, all you need to do is install http(with php moudle enabled) server and put your php code in the required directory and then restart your web server. Here is an example doc (Not very extensive but will help you to start) http://www.allaboutlinux.eu/how-to-run-php-on-ubuntu/